# how to do content based authorization?

Tags: sql, architecture, authorization

**Summary**

---

I have some complex database structure and I want to provide the data only to authorized members - the roles of whom also depend upon the data stored inside the database. It was working till now, but now that I want to expand the services, it is getting really complex. There has to be an elegant way.

*Note*: I am not using ASP.NET, so please don't suggest those remedies which are tightly bound to it, although I am open to ideas about modelling the authorization process.

**Background**

---

Alright, I had asked this question before too, but to my surprise, it didn't reap any good responses as such, so here I am posting it again in different words. I am working on a web app and have problem in how to model authorization process in an elegant way.

Let's say I have an app which provides the following services. There are 'projects'/workspaces where you can post something and also comment on those posts. The projects, which are deemed as 'open' can also be 'followed' - and hence the content is accessible to the followers. To bring this situation closer to my actual service, the project 'members' can decide what the followers have access to. This might (or might not!) look complex, but the actual app is more complex. What I did was to fill in the filtering code inside the sql queries themselves. Here's a code sample:

```
    public function getProjectById($id) {
        $auth = new Auth();
        $userid = $auth->getCurrentUserId();


        $sql = "
          SELECT P.id, P.userId, P.name, P.description,
                 P.creationTime, P.startTime, P.endTime, P.isOpen
          FROM       projects P
          INNER JOIN project_members PM
                      ON PM.projectid = P.id
                     AND P.id = '{id}'
                     AND (PM.userId = '{userid}' OR P.isOpen = 1)
        ";

        return $this->result($sql, array( "userid" => $userid, "id" => $id ));
    }
```

This looks bad, since I also have to provide this data to project followers (not shown here). And the complexity rises in the comments and posts - handling code. Now, is there a better way to do this - there must be. Should I separate out the authorization logic to other classes? Or/And should I use 'Views' in the database (completely unnecessary, but still i'd like to point out that they are not the MVC views)? Or is there still a better, clumsy-free way to solve this problem?

All suggestions are welcome - even those that aim at changing the database structure - although I wonder why that'd be required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with views, but since each call will need to pass the user ID, it sounds like what you really need are table-valued functions.  I'm most familiar with Microsoft SQL, where it would look something like this:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Projects AS P
     INNER JOIN dbo.AuthProjects(@UserID) AS AP ON P.ProjectID = AP.ProjectID
```

Note that the TVF literally returns a table, to which you would join to see which projects are available.  The TVF definition might look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AuthProjects(@UserID INT)
    RETURNS @Results TABLE (ProjectID INT NOT NULL, WriteAccess BIT NOT NULL)
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Results (ProjectID, WriteAccess)
        SELECT
            ProjectID, WriteAccess
        FROM
            Authorizations
        WHERE
            UserID = @UserID

    -- Additional logic for more ways a project may be authorized

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: oh! Thanks for your valuable answer, but i am afraid - I don't know much about MS SQL, since I am working with MySQL - and in my knowledge, this doesn't seem to work in MySQL...but really, thanks for taking interest in guiding me...

Comment: just now checked it up, and it supports functions! wow! I didn't know about it...oh! you don't know how much you've helped me....thanx!